# How to assign JSON object parameters to some values in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using angular 2.0. I have a json object returned by a method like this.

```
this.propertiesService.addSeriesToChart(this.testId).subscribe(result => {
        this.result = result;
        });
```

The addSeriesToChart() is in service which returns json object.

In the result returned, I have to assign some of the null values to few default values, I am trying like

```
if (this.result != undefined && this.result != null) {
  this.result.json().channel.mark = "ABC"
```

But the mark parameter inside the json object does not seem setting "ABC", it always remain null. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: could you please provide your JSON object here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can convert the an object to JSON using **result.JSON()** at the time of service when u send the response.And then when u collect that JSON object U have to convert it as  **this.result=JSON.stringify(result)** it work for mi

Comment: by using stringify, how can I asssign this.result.json().channel.mark ="ABC".

Comment: This is the json object after stringify.

Comment: I converted as this.result = result.json();     and this.result.channel.mark = "ABC" worked after that change.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a variable `data` in component class that you want to assign the data coming from json. You can use an `output` property to emit the data that you receive on subscribing.

You can do this:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  template: '<div>Hi</div>'
})

export class AppComponent{
data:Data;
@Output() dataOutput:EventEmitter<Data> =
new EventEmitter<Data>()

this.propertiesService.addSeriesToChart(this.testId).subscribe(result => {
            this.data = result.json();
            this.dataOutput.emit(this.data);
            });
}
```

Here `Data` will be your model containing variables that you can map the json to:

```
export class Data{
   id:number;
   name:string;
}
```

Now in order to use the above `AppComponent` elsewhere in your app, you can bind the event:

```
<user (dataOutput)="receiveData($event)"></user>



 export class PageComponent {
     datareceived:Data;
      constructor(){}
    receiveData(data){
         this.datareceived=data;
    }

     getUIData(value: any) {
            for (var name in value.selected) { 
               if (this.datareceived!= undefined && this.datareceived!= null) { 
                  if (name == 'mark') 
                     //do whatever you feel like 
                 } 
              } 
          }
    }
```

I think this will solve the case pretty much. I know this isn't exactly the solution as per your json but its a simplified way to get to it. Try with it.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Where are you calling the `getUIData` from? Its pretty ambiguous with the information that you have given.

Comment: So you want to change the original json that you received? Do you mind sharing your json.